# Can't use su command in adb shell

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Trying to become super user to access the /data/data directory but command not working

I'm trying it on the virtual device in android studio to access the file system but permission was denied tried to become super user but command does not work.

```
generic_x86:/data/data $ su
sh: su: not found
```

Is there anyway to fix this so that i can become the super user to view the files.

Comment: If you want root access in an emulator, you need to first run `adb root`.

Comment: tried using adb root but i am not able to get access to the file in the file system

Comment: If you're using an emulator with Google Play Services installed, it won't have root.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why but `su` does not work when you use the Nexus 5X emulator. If you use any other emulator the command works and you become super user.